# Python script won't exec from php when specific library is used

Tags: php, python, ros, rospy

Im trying to execute a Python script to get and set the parameter server in ROS. When I run any other simple python script that for example prints "Hello", I get back the value in PHP. But when I run this code:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
 import roslib
 import rospy
 import sys
 import re
 import string

 get = rospy.get_param("param")
 print get
```

I get an empty echo. However this code works fine in the terminal!

All I'm doing in PHP is:

```
 $output = exec("python path/script.py")
 echo $output;
```

I tried shell_exec, I tried with python in the command, and without. I also tried /usr/bin/python still it won't work for this specific code, but everything works for a simple print!

Comment: can you obtain any error?
try to find if there is an exception that causes an issue - something like:
<code>
    try:
         get = rospy.get_param("param")
    except BaseException as e:
         # save e to file
<\code>

Comment: `rospy` doesn't seem like it's been initialized before, should it be `roslib.rospy` or `roslib`? I don't know anything about the library, but I guess that might be the error.

Comment: @ishaan this is the way the library is imported, as I already stated, this code works perfectly on its own when I run it, however it doesnt work when I run it from PHP.

Comment: @IliyanBobev I get a blank document, i tested to see if it logs errors, it does log errors when I remove both roslib, and rospy, when they are imported nothing works.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't format code in the comment; Just place the `get = rospy.get_param("param")` in try-except. In the try section, attempt to save the value  of  get to text file, and in the except section attempt to catch the exception details and save those to a file. This way you'll have a log.

Comment: this is what I did, still its blank, nothing is written when the library is imported, I only start getting error logged when the "import rospy" is not here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that Apache's user doesnt have the required environment variables. So you have to add the environment variables paths you need in Apache's.. You can set them [out here](https://serverfault.com/questions/151328/setting-apache2-path-environment-variable)

Comment: Thank you for this answer! However I didn't understand how you add those environment variables for this particular case... Can you be more specific? (I know it's an old question)