# python import rpy2.robjects does not work when called from apache web request

Tags: python, r, rpy2

#### The problem:

I have a pretty simple python script (`Test.py`) in my `"C:\Apache24\htdocs\Test\cgi-bin"` folder which contains the following code:

```
#!/Python/python
print("Content-type: text/html")
print()
import os
os.environ['R_HOME'] = 'C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.1'
os.environ['R_USER'] = 'C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\rpy2'

# importing rpy2
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

# test : evaluating R code
robjects.r('''
        # create a function `f`
        f <- function(r, verbose=FALSE) {
            if (verbose) {
                cat("I am calling f().\n")
            }
            2 * pi * r
        }
        ''')

r_f = robjects.r['f']
res = r_f(3)
print(res[0])
```

Now when executing it in a python shell it works just fine. However, calling the script from a web request (even localhost) just loads the page indefinitely.

#### Additional info:

I'm working on a Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 OS via RemoteDesktopConnection

---

My installations are as follows:

```
Python 3.6: "C:\Python" + rpy2 version: 2.8.6

R 3.4.1: "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.1"

Apache: "C:\Apache24"
```

---

The `import os` and `os.environ['...` commands I have set up according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45484388/6912069) because I was not able to set it up with global system variables.

However I have the environment variables set (I am able to launch R in cmd.exe), but my rpy2 won't work (even in a python shell) without the above commands.

---

My system variables are:

```
Path: "...;C:\Python\Scripts\;C:\Python\;C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.1\bin\x64"

R_HOME: "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.1"

R_USER: "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\rpy2"
```

I know my apache server can execute python scripts as cgi (I have other python scripts which execute just fine via web request). It is really just the *import rpy2.robjects* command which makes the trouble

---

I have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34935438/6912069) while searching for a solution, but I don't know very much about server configuration and am not able to do something without a more detailed explanation.

---

Let me know if I can provide more details.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: See this question: [Why are Python environment variables different when executed from a web server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21324027/why-are-python-environment-variables-different-when-executed-from-a-web-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it was the most obvious/stupid thing that happened. In my python script using forward slash instead of backslash did solve my issue. So my updated code looks as follows:

```
#!/Python/python
print("Content-type: text/html")
print()
import os
os.environ['PYTHONHOME'] = 'C:/Python'
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = 'C:/Python/lib/site-packages'
os.environ['R_HOME'] = 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.1'
os.environ['R_USER'] = 'C:/Python/Lib/site-packages/rpy2'

# importing rpy2
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

# test : evaluating R code
robjects.r('''
        # create a function `f`
        f <- function(r, verbose=FALSE) {
            if (verbose) {
                cat("I am calling f().\n")
            }
            2 * pi * r
        }
        ''')

r_f = robjects.r['f']
res = r_f(3)
print(res[0])
```

This script executed the way it is supposed to when being called via a web request.